# Is Black Hole a Knockback?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Is the spell [Black Hole](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/black-hole) counted as knockback? It would be insane with [Strongarm Bracers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/strongarm-bracers).

I've googled it and some people say it does, while others say it doesn't, does anyone have an offical statement about that or tested this on his own?

Comment: If you compare the videos for any skills with knockback (e.g. Seismic Slam) and Black Hole, it looks like BH does not have knockback. Enemies are not knocked back.

Comment: At first enemies struck in BH are pulled towards the center of the hole, and after it ends they are 'knocked' out of the black hole, which made me wonder about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the majority of the posts of the D3 forums, it DOES count.

This is the best explanation I found: Knockback tends to refer to any effect that moves the target, usually making them airborne. The direction of the movement tends to be irrelevant for it to count as "knockback".

A very good thread about Black Hole and knockback can be found here: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12373517571

Comment: Wow. I need to find those bracers. That plus the Spellsteal black hole...

Comment: Interesting... this has fun implications for the Monk ability [Cyclone Strike](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/cyclone-strike) as well!

Comment: Addition: per [this thread](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11913192267), Cyclone Strike *is* a knockback. Since Cyclone Strike pulls monsters in like Black Hole, this also supports Black Hole being a knockback.

Comment: that opens some awesome build options then (:

Comment: Indeed it does...good luck and happy farming.

Comment: @Werdli Oh yes, the strongarms bracers are awesome for just about every class.  Also they synergize super well with a monk's deadly reach's knockup which also procs it.