# What counts as knockbacks for Strongarm Bracers?

Tags: diablo-iii

[Strongarm Bracers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/strongarm-bracers) have the secondary property that any knockbacks increase damage 20-30% for 5 seconds. What counts as knockbacks for purposes of the damage increase?

A number of skills pull creatures in, but does it classify as a knockback for the damage increase of Strongarm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Black Hole a Knockback?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167076/is-black-hole-a-knockback)

Answer (score 3):

Knowing which skills count as knockback can only be confirmed through testing, but see the list below for confirmed skills and some insight. At least for Monks, pulling monsters in counts as knockback (all runes of Cyclone Strike confirmed).

List of confirmed Monk skills that proc Stongarm --

- Fist of Thunder - Thunderclap
- Deadly Reach (knock-up)
- Lashing Tail Kick - Sweeping Armada
- Tempest Rush - Bluster
- Wave of Light - Wall of Light
- Cyclone Strike - all runes

List of confirmed Monk skills that DO NOT proc Stongarm --

- Thundergod's Vigor

I'm not sure about non-Monk skills, but this may give insight into Blizzard's wording on what they consider knockback. Source: [Druin's monk mechanic workshop](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12506331470). At the time of posting this, the link's content is up to date as of 2.0.6 and later 2.1 PTR builds.

Answer (score 1):

Barbarian skill wise here is a confirmed list I was able to find on the [Battle.net forums](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12329703286?page=3#47):

> Strongarm Bracers tested and confirmed to work after:
>
> - Cleave Scattering Blast knockback
> - Seismic Slam Shattered Ground knockback
> - Seismic Slam Stagger, Rumble, Strength from Earth and Permafrost knockup
> - Whirlwind Hurricane pull
> - Ancient Spear Ranseur knockback
> - Ancient Spear Harpoon and Rage Flip drag
> - Ground Stomp Wrenching Smash pull
> - Leap Toppling Impact knockback
> - Leap Call of Arreat pull
> - Sprint Gangway knockback
> - Revenge Grudge
> - Furious Charge (all runes) knockback
> - Avalanche Snow-Capped Mountain push
> - Earthquake Cave-In pull